# Prevent jQuery addon from loading multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to change the content of my pages without refreshing the actual page, therefore the specific *scripts* and *addons* for each page do load through AJAX too.

The problem is with **Google Maps API**, I had to include it in every page, because otherwise it doesn't work, but because of that it shows a console error that it's being loaded multiple times `You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

I already know how to check if it's loaded, but I don't know how to prevent it from loading again:

```
if(google && google.maps){
  //Code to prevent loading the addon again
}
```

How do I **prevent loading** *google maps* (or any other addon) **more than once**?

Comment: Why are you not loading all of the scripts in the parent page one time?

Comment: For my more complex pages, I use a minifier to combine the libs I use with my js pages into one single minified file to load.

Comment: @Bindrid I can't use them all on one page, because if the page the user loads at first isn't the the page with the plugins, then none of them would actually work. I don't think a minifier would solve this, since the Google Maps API would still be loaded again and again, even if it's minified :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider to replace *static* file reference:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

to dynamic one, for example:

```
function ensureGoogleApi() {
    if (typeof google === "undefined" || typeof google.maps === "undefined") {
        return $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js');
    }
    return new $.Deferred().resolve(google.maps);
}
```

where [`$.getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) is used to load Google Maps API

**Example**

```js
ensureGoogleApi()
    .then(function () {
        initMap();
    });





function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
    });
}



function ensureGoogleApi() {
    if (typeof google === "undefined" || typeof google.maps === "undefined") {
        return $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key');
    }
    return new $.Deferred().resolve(google.maps);
}
```

```css
 #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```